# Sending data between ruby and objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ruby

I'm trying to serialize data for sharing between Ruby and Objective-C.  I would like to use something lightweight like YAML or JSON, but I would be curious to hear what would be the easiest implementation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to go with JSON, there's the [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) for Objective-C which seems to be pretty mature and is used by well known applications such as Adium and Twitterfon.

Here is a [neat and simple article](http://zachwaugh.com/2009/01/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c/) which shows how to use it.

I also recommend [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for the server communication you will be doing. Makes things a lot neater and easier.

Answer (score 1):

If suitable, A Ruby/Objective-C bridge, such as [RubyObjC](http://rubyobjc.com/) or [RubyCocoa](http://rubycocoa.sourceforge.net/HomePage), will obviate the need to serialize data.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [ruby extension](http://github.com/kballard/osx-plist) for this very purpose, which allows ruby to read/write property lists. This requires no extra libraries on the obj-c side, and you can install the ruby library via rubygems.